# I'm not allowed to show data from a new version (v2) of aDribbble API

Tags: javascript

I was using a Dribbble api v1 and it was successfully in feching data. Then it stoped to return because the v1 become deprecated. Later I made a new app version using the v2 api and I got a new 'access_token' and it continuing not showing.

Overview for the v2 Dribble API
https://developer.dribbble.com/v2/

When I put this URL in the browser:

https://api.dribbble.com/v2/user?access_token=1323213h23h2131j2h3jk12

it returns succefully my personal data from my account. It proves that my tolken is working.

But in my App I want to return popular shots from all users and it doesn' return nothing:

**NOTE:** This code was been working when I was using v1 Dribbble api. I made this using ReactJS but the Knowledge of this tool is not mandatory to understand the problem. It is something wrong that have to do with v2 Dribbble api.

```
 export default class DribbblesList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { page: 1, shots: [], showModal: false };
    this.getShots = this.getShots.bind(this);   
 }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getShots();
  }

  getShots() {
    this.setState({
    dataFetched: false
    })

    return $.getJSON('https://api.dribbble.com/v2/shots?page=' + 
    this.state.page + '&access_token=sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf')    
   .then((resp) => {

    var newShots = this.state.shots.concat(resp.data);
      this.setState({
        page: this.state.page + 1,
        shots: newShots,
        dataFetched: true
      });

     console.log(resp)
   });
  }

render() {
  const shots = this.state.shots.map((data, i) => {
    return (
      <div>        
        <Dribbble data={data} key={i} />          
      </div>
    )
  });
```

**Error Message:** No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Does anybody know how to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)